# I need to return a string in cocoa after http request and xml delegates are complete?

Tags: cocoa, cocoa-touch

I have the following delegate method of NSURLConnection

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
```

{

```
    NSLog(@"DONE, Receive bytes: %d", [webData length]);

NSString *theXML = [[NSString alloc]initWithBytes:[webData mutableBytes] length:[webData length] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
//NSLog(theXML);
[theXML release];

if(xmlParser)
{
    [xmlParser release];        
}
else 
{
    xmlParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc]initWithData:webData];
    [xmlParser setDelegate:self];
    [xmlParser setShouldResolveExternalEntities:YES];
    [xmlParser parse];
    [connection release];
    [webData release];
    NSLog(@"\n\n\n\n");
    NSLog(httpResult);
}
```

I want to return `httpResult` - how do i do this?  I have the above method in a class.  I create an instance of this class in another controller class which calls a function to create an http request.  This function then in turn calls this delegate method.  How do i return `httpResult` to the controller class?

**I have figured it out - thanks guys**

Answer (score 3):

Give that class either a delegate or a didFinish-type callback and set that to tell your controller when it's done.

Comment: can u provide me a specific code of example of how to do this